# Is there a way to get the python3 requests library to send a list of data for a bulk PATCH request?

Tags: python-3.x, api, http, python-requests

I am working with a particular API which has an endpoint for bulk partial update of objects using a PATCH request. The API endpoint accepts a JSON list of dictionaries. The following command succeeds and returns the updated objects as desired:

```
$ curl -X PATCH \
       -H "Authorization: Token abcde" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       "example.com/api/objects" \
       --data="[{'id': 1, 'value': 100}, {'id': 2, 'value': 200}]"
```

However, the following Python3 snippet does not succeed:

```
import requests

headers = { "Authorization": "Token abcde",
            "Content-Type": "application/json" }
data = "[{'id': 1, 'value': 100}, {'id': 2, 'value': 200}]"

response = requests.patch("example.com/api/objects", headers=headers, data=data)

if response.status_code != 200:
  print(f"{response.status_code}: {response.reason}")
print(response)
```

This returns the following:

```
400: Bad Request
{'non_field_errors': ['Expected a list of items but got type "dict".']}
```

My understanding of this is that the requests library must be doing some interpretation of the string provided to the `data` parameter.

According to the [Python3 requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/), the `data` parameter should be a "dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request." Alternatively, one can use the `json` parameter, which should be "a JSON serializable Python object to send in the body of the Request."

I have tried the above snippet like so:

```
response = requests.patch("example.com/api/objects", headers=headers, json=data)
```

The result is the same `400: Bad Request` error. I have also tried providing a Python list object instead of a string to both the `data` and `json` parameters, like so:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'value': 100}, {'id': 2, 'value': 200}]
```

Those both produce the same `400: Bad Request` error.

Am I doing something wrong here? How can one get the requests library to pass on a string literally in whatever request one is making?

Comment: Can you try: `data = [{'id': 1, 'value': 100}, {'id': 2, 'value': 200}]` (note, it's not string but standard python dict). and then `response = requests.patch("example.com/api/objects", headers=headers, json=data)` (note the `json=` parameter)

Comment: Hi, this produces the same `400: Bad Request` result. I just re-confirmed that now.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, `curl` appears to automatically include a trailing backslash at the end of a URL it's given when it actually performs the request. The Python3 Requests library does not do this. The API was expecting a trailing backslash in the URL, and without that, the API didn't know how to handle the request.

Changing the above snippet like so produced the desired behavior:

```
response = requests.patch("example.com/api/objects/", headers=headers, json=data)
```

Note the trailing backslash in the URL.